# multiple commands produce assets problem (xcode11)

Tags: swift, xcode

This is error that I got.

Multiple commands produce

`'/Users/Bank/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Food_Passion-dzzejipxsitbfkfjyjzppmertjri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Food Passion UAT.app/Assets.car':
1) Target 'Food Passion UAT' (project 'Food Passion') has compile command with input '/Users/Bank/Documents/AppDevelop/FoodPassion/Food Passion/Assets.xcassets'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Food Passion UAT' (project 'Food Passion'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”`

I try to remove assets folder from `BuildPhase --> Copy Bundle Resources`. It works without any error but the cannot access to assets folder

Anyone know hot to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Same here. It's happened many times, in many projects. I simply don't know the proper place to put them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is Pods-${yourApp}-resources.sh file will find *.xcassets file and your Asset.xcassets file has been processed twice.  Modify resources.sh file or remove your .xcassets file from Copy Bundle Resources should work.